# Massege: Undefined Index: in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Show error

A php error was encountered

severity notice

Message: Undefined index: am & so on

Model

```
public function schbysempaid($batch, $sem){
$result = array();
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE curem=$sem AND baid=$batch");
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $querys=$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(install.adfee) as am,SUM(install.lifee) as lb,SUM(install.tfee) as tt,SUM(install.enrfee) as enr,SUM(install.refee) as re,SUM(install.spofee) as spo,SUM(install.exfee) as ex FROM stu JOIN install ON install.sid=stu.sid Where install.sid='".$row['sid']."' AND install.curem=$sem AND stu.curem=$sem AND stu.baid=$batch AND install.paid=1");
        $result[] = $querys->result_array();
}

return $result;
    }
```

Controller

```
  public function searchsubmit()
{
        $batch=$this->input->post('srch');
        $sem=$this->input->post('srch1');
        $data['result']=$this->law_model->schbysempaid($batch, $sem);
        $this->load->view('admission/dashboard',$data);
}
```

View

```
foreach($result as $paid){
                          <td><?php echo $paid['am'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['lb'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['tt'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['spo'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['ex'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['enr'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['re'] ?></td>
}
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! I know that codeigniter has other ways to access the database than building full insecure queries like that.

Comment: There is no record in $result. Try print_r($result) before for each and say what is the output?

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($result)`. It won't look the way you expect. You're currently creating an array containing other multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: I have used  print_r($result) this show all data but in the table generate an error undefined index

Comment: could use a < pre> html tag to format the array but yes, dump it first to verify whether some data is returned from your model or not

Comment: show the result of `print_r($result)`

Comment: actually, u need to check like that: `foreach($result as $value){
foreach ($value as $paid) {
 
}
}`

Comment: Thanks Dear devpro

Comment: ahan, khushaamded